# Shouldn't we have just one "retag" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [manga-retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-retag) and [anime-retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-retag) have been added to enable new users to request for a retag, but isn't a single [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind it was that a new user would try to tag their question with the series (which doesn't exist), then their next try would be either [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) or [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga), since they're blacklisted, we have both these tags so that when the user types either "anime" and "manga", they'll find it.

---

[retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) was created, [anime-retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-retag) and [manga-retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-retag) were synonymed to it.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just make 1 tag of it then ?  anime-manga-retag ?

Comment: @Dimitrimx: I think a better course of action is to create a [tag:retag] tag, and synonym both to it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Sounds like a even beter plan