# Having a "retag" tag show up by default

Tags: feature-request

Related to: [Shouldn't we have just one "retag" tag?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/398/99)
Have a look at: https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/5921/1

A new user posted a comment within the question asking for retagging, and chose [symbolism](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) as the tag. Would it be a good idea to have the *retag* tag visible by default, similar to how *discussion*, *feature-request*, *support*, and *bug* show up here on meta?

While I agree with Madara's answer there, there is a possibility that a new user who wants to ask question on a series we haven't tagged before, would be confused, especially if they are new to Stack Exchange network as well.

While they could arbitrarily choose some random tag, it is much cleaner to enable them to use the *retag* tag more easily.

Comment: [tag:retag] was removed by [this edit](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/4/revisions), presumably by accident. It seems like more work to maintain than it's worth, considering there are usually people in chat who see every question and can fix wrong tags when an incorrectly tagged question arrives. I'd like for us to be more welcoming to new users with questions about series we don't have tags for, but I'm not sure if this hackjob is the best way to do it, since it's not how tags are supposed to be used.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, it doesn't occur quite as often, so the way it currently stands is fine with me.

Comment: The only problem is that if a new user asks a first question on a "new" series, and sees that their tag is not available, they might mistakenly assume that this site is restricted to certain series only, and leave. I guess it would still make sense to have some kind of a "if you don't know what to do, use this" tag, until the user has 100 reputation. This also ensures that users who get the "free" 100 reputation from other SE sites would be above the threshold.