# What should I call the BNA/Brand New Animal/Bī enu ē tag?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to make a new tag for [Studio Trigger's BNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNA:_Brand_New_Animal) as I noticed there was no tag for it.
I also didn't see any best practice guides here or in the help section about how to create a tag for an anime/manga.

Not sure what I should call the new tag for this anime so I wanted a second opinion:

- `BNA`
- `brand-new-animal`
- romaji `bi-enu-e`

I'm temped to pick either of the first two. My qualm with the first is I don't know what to do if there is some other anime/manga that already uses this short hand name. Nor do I know what will happen if I use `BNA` and then some other anime/manga is made that also goes by "`BNA`" when the tag already exists for Studio Trigger's BNA.

Thoughts?

Comment: [Does this perhaps answer the question?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/522/1458)

Comment: Thanks I couldn't find anything helpful. Can this be moved/added to the [anime stack exchange help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=tag) somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on personal preference:

1. I think [bna-brand-new-animal](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bna-brand-new-animal) can be a good compromise considering that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNA:_Brand_New_Animal) and [Fandom Wiki](https://brand-new-animal.fandom.com/wiki/BNA:_Brand_New_Animal) use *BNA: Brand New Animal*.
2. Otherwise, create [brand-new-animal](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brand-new-animal) (and optionally, synonymize [bna](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bna) to it), as per [How do we want to name series tags?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/521/2516).
3. I don't think 'bi-enu-e' (certainly not with the diacritics) is something that people commonly use to refer to it.

<sup>That said, [creating a new tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) needs 300 rep, and without existing questions, the tag cannot be created. Consider using [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) instead for the moment, as per [Shouldn't we have just one "retag" tag?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/398/2516).</sup>

Comment: I like `bna-brand-new-animal`. That fixes a lot of the issues and makes it clear "which bna" if there are multiple. Also I didn't know that tags now need 300 rep. I thought I read in one of the older meta posts it was 150. Thanks for letting me know! :)

Comment: @Wimateeka ah, the 150 rep was when the site hadn't got its site design yet. After that, [the rep threshold was raised](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4251/2516).